# Android dateformat to string issue

Tags: android, date-format, simpledateformat

I want to convert : Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016 to 02/02/2012.

I did

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
  Date date = sdf.parse(mydate);
```

but its give error Unparseable date: "Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016" (at offset 0) any idea how i can parse it ?

Comment: change z to zzzz, let me know if it worked

Comment: like this -> sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

Comment: nope still getting same error

Comment: also not work  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"); too

Comment: Would you post the whole code please?

Comment: String dt= hbbean.getTarih().toString(); its returns (Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016)  than  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
  Date date = sdf.parse(dt); and get exception.

Comment: try my answer, it worked for me.

Comment: instead of String dt= hbbean.getTarih().toString(); try String mydate = "Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016";run my code exactly, I guess something is wrong with "hbbean.getTarih()" method

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    String mydate = "Wed Apr 06 09:37:00 GMT+03:00 2016";
    SimpleDateFormat src = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat dest = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = src.parse(mydate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //handle exception
    }
    String result = dest.format(date);
```

Output :

```
06/04/2016
```

### PS:

> Z
>   time zone (RFC 822)
>   (Time Zone)
>   Z/ZZ/ZZZ:-0800 ZZZZ:GMT-08:00 ZZZZZ:-08:00